# Flutter web refuse to connect on port 8080

Tags: flutter-web

I am trying to start my flutter web app on port 8080 but the chrome is giving me error. A couple context:

- `flutter doctor` is all good
- I am on flutter 2.0.6
- I start the app with command `flutter run -d chrome --web-port=8080`
- After start the app on port 8080, the only app using port 8080 is dart

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dart    57589 ****   *** *******     0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

The page basically hang there and eventually giving me the following error:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED localhost refused to connect.
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?